# Hover over element?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, hover

Using Visual Studio and Selenium I'm trying to hover over an element in a drop-down menu so that I can click on the "hidden" element within. It is not possible to just click , I have to hover.

I tried several different ways without success:

First I tried to just hover over the first element like this:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement hoverElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("xpath adress here')]")));
builder.MoveToElement(hoverElement).Build().Perform();
```

This method made the first dropdown element be "marked" but the dropdown didn't open up for some reason so I could not click on the second element.

Then I tried to both hover over the first element and in the same command also click on the second element:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement hoverElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("xpath adress here')]")));
builder.MoveToElement(hoverElement).MoveToElement(wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("second xpath adress")))).Click().Build().Perform();
```

This did not work at all. The first element did not even get "marked". The test just timed out after 10 seconds.

So now I'm trying to use a locator instead:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement hoverElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("xpath adress for first element')]")));
builder.MoveToElement(hoverElement).Perform();
By locator = By.XPath("2nd element xpath");
driver.click(locator);
```

But I can not execute this test because IWebDriver does not contain a definition for click. I get this error when I try to write:

```
driver.click
```

Any suggestions?

First element:

```
By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'item-text')][contains(text(),'Change')]"
```

Second element:

```
By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'item-text')][contains(text(),'Create Change Order')]"
```

UPDATE:

HTML structure for the section of the hover drop-down menu looks like this:

```
<div class="topbar-menu-dd responsive-dropdown-menu add">
   <div class="scrollable-dropdown-menu scrollable-dropdown-menu-root dropdown- 
    menu dropdown-menu-root dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-root dropdown 
    dropdown-root responsive-dropdown-menu-root active">
      <div class="no-native-scrollbars  scroller-content">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu-wrap" tabindex="1">
             <li class="item topbar-menu-dd-item item-submenu" id="699143f1- 
              e470-49f0-99f4-a96fee365260/c171" title name="699143f1-e470-49f0- 
              99f4-a96fee365260/c171">
                 <div class="item item-template" id="699143f1-e470-49f0-99f4- 
                 a96fee365260/c171">
                    <span class="item-text">Change</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="next-icon">
                    <span class="fonticon fonticon-right-open">
                    ::before
                    </span>
                 </div>
             </li>
   ...
   <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-root responsive  scroller scroller- 
   root bottom-right conceal">
      <div class="no-native-scrollbars  scroller-content">
         <ul class="dropdown-menu-wrap" tabindex="1">
            <li class="item item-back" id="itm-a7b1b6" title>
               <div class="back-icon">
               <span class="item-text">Change</span>
            </li>
            <li class="item topbar-menu-dd-item" id="cbf405dc-5f99-4efd-810d- 
            a69666da9c75/c172" title name="cbf405dc-5f99-4efd-810d- 
            a69666da9c75/c172">
               <div class="item item-template" id="cbf405dc-5f99-4efd-810d- 
            a69666da9c75/c172">
                  <span class="item-text">Create Change Order</span>
               </div>
           </li>
   ...
</div>
```

the "..." I added to indicate other part of the code that is not relevant.

When I hover the mouse over "Change" the "Create Change order" is revealed and I can click on it.
[image]

Comment: Show ur element code

Comment: Show ur element HTML code
Cant understand it's sctructure. Why u must hover something instead of just click a dropdown and then click a menu item?

Comment: @Somber It is not possible to open up the different list items in the drop-down menu by clicking, nothing happens when you click, instead you have to hover the mouse cursor over the list item you want to expand.

I've added the HTML structure in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only using hover (`MoveToElement`) was not enough to activate and expand the dropdown menu. I needed to also move the mouse slightly using `MoveByOffset`.

After the menu was expanded I had no problem clicking on the second element.

```
//1. Hover mouse over "Change" and move it slightly to the left to open up the menu
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var DropDown1 = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'item-text')][contains(text(),'Change')]")));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(DropDown1).Perform();
action.MoveByOffset(-10, -10).Perform();

//2. Click on "Create Change Order"
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'item-text')][contains(text(),'Create Change Order')]"))).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the custom made click function for C# Selenium.

```
public async Task<bool> TryClick(By by, int mode = 0)
{
   try
   {
       if (mode == 0)
       {
           Driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click('');", ((RemoteWebDriver)Driver).FindElement(by));
       }
       else if (mode == 1)
       {
           Driver.FindElement(by).Click();
       }
       else if (mode == 2)
       {
           Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
           action.MoveToElement(Driver.FindElement(by)).Perform();
           action.Click(Driver.FindElement(by)).Perform();
       }

       return true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex) { }
   return false;
}
```

According to my experience, at least one of the above 3 methods worked on all scenarios.
Furthermore, we can check if an exception occurred or not by checking the return value of the function.
You can use this function as follows.

```
By first = By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'item-text')][contains(text(),'Change')]";
if(!await TryClick(first,0)) // If this does not work, try 1 and 2 for the second parameter
{
    // Failed to click
}
By second = By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'item-text')][contains(text(),'Create Change Order')]";
if(!await TryClick(second,0)) // If this does not work, try 1 and 2 for the second parameter
{
    // Failed to click
}
```

I am not sure if this would help or not.
But as @Somber mentioned, if you share the URL and explain what to achieve, it would be much better to get help.

Comment: I tried using Actions as you suggested but got an error: 
"Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : javascript error: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined" 

Not really sure what that means.

I also tried using  "Driver.ExecuteScript" as you suggested but my driver does not contain "ExcecuteScript".

I have updated the question with part of the HTML code now if you want to take a look.

Comment: Could you share the link? I want to test on my side first.

Comment: Unfortunately not possible. The page is only accessible through the company I work for.